# How to extract the Rationale and Problem applied to a Requirement artifact in Enterprise Architect through API

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have a few requirements defined in the Requirement Diagram as shown in the below picture. I want to fetch the Rationale and Problem that are attached to the Requirement through API.

The DB has no relationship between the *Requirement* and *Note* in the *t_object* table. Do I have to look up in some other table? Please suggest.

[image]

Comment: I guess the notes were created with Advanced/Show Element Feature?

Comment: No, they were created with New Child Element -> Attach Rationale or Problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EA.Elements`(t_object) are connected with each other using `EA.Connector` (t_connector)

So in order to get from your requirement to your note, you can do something like this

```
foreach (EA.Connector connector in myRequirement.Connectors)
{
    EA.Element otherElement;
    if (connector.ClientID != myRequirement.ElementID)
    {
        otherElement = myRepository.GetElementByID(connector.ClientID)
    }
    else
    {
        otherElement = myRepository.GetElementByID(connector.ClientID)
    }
    if (otherElement.Type == "Note")
    {
        return otherElement;
    }
}
```

In a query you can something like this

```
select note.* 
from t_object o
inner join t_connector c on o.Object_ID in (c.Start_Object_ID, c.End_Object_ID)
inner join t_object note on note.Object_ID in (c.Start_Object_ID, c.End_Object_ID)
                            and note.Object_Type = 'Note'
where o.ea_guid = '<myRequirementGUID>'
```